# Is it Possible to Use Images from Drawable as Icons in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to kotlin jetpack compose and I was wondering if I could use a custom image from my drawable as my icon. I have this sealed class BottomBarScreen and has 3 objects.[image]

I've tried using a composable but it just omits an error called "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function." I hope someone can enlighten me on this matter, thank you^^

Answer (score 0):

I also pass resources as a parameter. You can check the below examples.

---

MenuItem.kt

---

```
data class MenuItem(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val contentDescription: String,
    val icon: Painter
)
```

**Data**

```
@Composable
private fun prepareNavigationDrawerItems(): List<MenuItem> {
    val itemsList = arrayListOf<MenuItem>()

    itemsList.add(
        MenuItem(
            id = "contact_us",
            title = stringResource(R.string.contact_us),
            contentDescription = "Contact Us",
            icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.contact_us)
        )
    )
    return itemsList
}
```

**Final Screen**

```
@Composable
fun MyCompleteDrawer() {
    val itemsList = prepareNavigationDrawerItems()
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 20.dp)
    ) {

        items(itemsList) { item ->
            NavigationListItem(item = item) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```